# Determining array's coordinates with a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

The title is already saying. I need to determinate array's coordinates with a string.
As for example: if I want to move the value `1` to the right twice, I'm going to write in my `seed` variable: `"rr"`. The `r` means that the value will be moved one index to the right.

In this link: http://jsfiddle.net/Kike/hVczZ/ I'm explaining better.

Comment: Is your array always 5x5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works if the movement is possible :

```
for(var t = array.length; t >= 0; t--){
    if(array[t]==1){
        move(t,seed);
        break;
    }
}

function move(index,movements){
    var size=5;
    var x=index % size; 
    var y= Math.floor(index / size);
    for(var i=0;i<movements.length;i++){
        var pos=movements[i];
        if(pos=='r'){
            if(x+1 == size){
                x=0;
                y+=1;
            }else{x+=1;}
        }else if(pos=='l'){
            if(x==0){
                y-=1;
                x=size-1;
            }else{x-=1;}
        }else if(pos=='u'){
            y-=1;
        }else if(pos=='d'){
            y+=1;
        }
    }
    array[index]=0;
    array[size*y+x]=1;
}

console.log(array) // 1 is in fourth position
```